# Can I alternate my SVG viewBox property using CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have this SVG

```
<svg height="210" width="400" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
<path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z"/></svg>
```

And I would like to change the viewBox property using CSS. It would probably look something like this. But I tried this and it does not work.

```
.svg {
  viewBox: "100 100 100 100";
}
```

I figured this is probably not possible but I am wondering what my next best option is to alternate this in a clean-easy way.

Comment: You can't viewBox is an attribute and not a CSS property. Change it via javascript.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you are tackling the problem the wrong way. In your case, changing the viewBox like your are doing is equivalent to simply translate the path inside and this is something you can do with CSS:

```css
svg:first-of-type path {
  transform:translate(-100px,-100px);
}
```

```html
<svg height="210" width="400" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
<path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" fill="red"/></svg>

<svg height="210" width="400" viewBox="100 100 100 100">
<path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" fill="red"/></svg>
```

Comment: With this approach, you would always have to keep in mind the values the SVG has before translating. My goal is to set all the values without having to note the old ones.

Comment: @NielsBosman then you have to use JS, I tried to give a solution based on your case.